# Android Facebook Deeplink redirecting to Google Play Store

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I have implemented Deep-linking within my android app. 
I want to send links through Facebook Messenger to my friends and when they click on it the app will open if it is installed, otherwise the Google Play Store should open to install the app.

I have the following intent filter in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="christmascards" />
 </intent-filter>
```

This is what I put in the params which I send to facebook to get my canonical url:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("access_token", accessToken);
    params.putString("name", "Christmas Cards Link");
    params.putString("android", "[{\"app_name\": \""+getString(R.string.app_name)+"\" ," +
            "\"class\":\"\"," +
            "\"package\":\"com.iovchev.christmascards\"," +
            "\"url\":\"christmascards://postcard?id="+cardId+"\"}]"
            );
```

This is what I send to the Messenger when I get my canonical URL:

```
FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder = 
new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(SendCardActivity.this)
.setLink(url)
.setName("Christmas Card For You")
.setCaption("Share amazing christmas cards with your friends.")
.setPicture("http://i.imgur.com/L2KlJWQ.png")
.setDescription("To view my amazing post card just click on the link here. You must have     Christmas Cards app for Android.");
 FacebookDialog dialog = builder.build();
 dialog.present();
```

And whenever I click on the message in messenger I always get redirected to Google Play Store. Previously everything worked without any problem and still when I try to open the old messages my app opens. The only difference before now and then was that I had ios params for the app.

I want to receive the custom schema which I send with the data in it (I mean the postcard id) and use it in my HomeActivity, that is why i removed the content of the class field (when it is set it was sending an empty intent without the url I provide).

The access token field is a combination of "app_id|app_secret"

What I have tried:

1. Add ios param just to check if everything is working - Not working
2. Force stop and clear facebook and messenger apps - Not working
3. Add the class field to the android pasams as com.iovchev.christmascards.HomeActivity - Not working
4. Recheck Hash keys - Not working
5. Change positions of the categories in the intent-filter - Not working

Any ideas?

**Update 1:**

For the old links when you click on the link the messenger throws the following intent:

```
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=christmascards://postcard?id=Vi9XTnj85R&target_url=https://fb.me/1509516792632317
```

That is why my app is started.

For the new links it throws the following intent:

```
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://fb.me/624376077674657 cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main}.
```

That is Why my app is not started.

**Update 2:**

When you share the link using

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
.setLink(url)
.build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Everything is OK. So a messenger problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/831404546921822/ Here is the logged bug. It is actully a bug in Facebook Messenger for Android.